# .NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.1 is not supported on this operating system - for Software Developer through Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, frameworks

I have developed software using C# on Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 Operating System.

My client is having Windows 7 Ultimate - (Not SP1)

and is getting below message:
NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.1 is not supported on this operating

What settings should I use in Visual Studio so that it will not ask to install 4.6.1

In project Application tab,I already selected Target Framework as .NET Framework 3.5 as below

[image]

,still it's asking :

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112889/why-is-net-framework-4-7-2-not-supported-on-this-operating-system-windows-1/54136461#54136461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft tells it best at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx but to sum it up:

1. Right Click the solution and choose Properties
2. Select the Application tab
3. In the Target Framework dropdown list choose the framework that you know to be the minimally installed version on your target computer(s).

Also, when creating your new project, you have the option at that time to select the targeted framework.

Comment: In Application Tab ,I selected .NET Framework 3.5 and then rebuild setup,still getting message on client machine as :This setup requires .Net Framework v4.6.1

Comment: How are you deploying this?

Comment: 1.Right click on solution 2.Add New Project 3. In Visual Studio Installer Tab ,I select Setup Project named as "Guru", 4.I include all files in Application folder,create shortcuts in User's Desktop Folder 5.Right click on Guru,then select build (for prerequisites,I unchecked to Create setup program to install prerequisites components)

Comment: What's the targeted framework of that project? I'm not at my computer to verify but I'm pretty sure it has it's own.

Comment: You are right Sir.Setup project was taking .net framework 4.6.1. I changed its .net targeted framework and problem solved :D