# Why is .Net Framework 4.7.2 "not supported on this operating system"? (Windows 10)

Tags: .net, .net-4.7.2

I was trying to install the .NET 472 developer pack on a Windows 10 machine, and got this error.

[image]

I have been able to install this on other Win10 PCs, and also on Win7. So it doesn't make any obvious sense why it claims to be "not supported".

In the log there are some version checks:

> Bundle condition evaluated to false:
>
> ((VersionNT = v6.1 AND
>   ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR      (VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT
>   (OSInstallationType = "Client")) OR      (VersionNT = v6.3) OR
>   (VersionNT = v10.0 AND OSBuildNumber >= 14393) OR      (VersionNT >
>   v10.0))

*but that doesn't clearly indicate (to me) what I need to do to resolve the problem.* Some Windows update is missing, perhaps?

Thanks

---

Microsoft has [a support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations) which includes this error, but there is no pertinent resolution:

> The .NET Framework 4.5*.x*/4.6*.x*/4.7*.x* is not supported on this operating system:
>
> *For failed installations of the .NET Framework on Windows 7 ... [all
>   specific to Win7 / nothing for Win10]*

---

FYI the entire log file contains:

```
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:04]i001: Burn v3.11.0.1701, Windows v10.0 (Build 10240: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\abcdef\AppData\Local\Temp\{D35ACDD2-93C0-4D99-BC39-6A30F2822134}\.cr\NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:04]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'IgnorePendingReboot' to value '0'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:04]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\abcdef\Downloads\NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=420 -burn.filehandle.self=428'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\abcdef\Downloads\NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\abcdef\Downloads\'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\abcdef\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.7.2_Developer_Pack_20190109094808.log'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[1F70:1DA0][2019-01-09T09:48:08]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '4.7.3081.0'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Policies\WiX\Burn'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i052: Condition 'NOT NetFxBurnPackageCacheDirectory' evaluates to true.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'NetFxBurnPackageCacheDirectory' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'netfxfullrefresh_43_CBSValue' to value '1'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'netfxfullrefresh_43_OS_BuildNumber' to value '10240'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'NetFxFullRefresh_InstalledRelease' to value '393295'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting numeric variable 'NetFxFullRefresh_InstalledReleaseExists' to value 1
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'OSBuildNumber' to value '10240'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting string variable 'OSInstallationType' to value 'Client'
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015GenericBootstrapperInstalled' to value 1
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: File search: wfs7886F3974B7A650CE7C1C92244670750, did not find path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\NetFxDevpack_FullRefreshISV_4.7.2_461833\packages\dotnetframework\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting numeric variable 'NetFxIsvRefreshIsCached' to value 0
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: File search: wfsB2051303457C358B8576A6E6F250B3C4, did not find path: C:\Users\abcdef\Downloads\\packages\dotnetframework\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i000: Setting numeric variable 'NetFxIsvRefreshExists' to value 0
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i052: Condition 'NetFxIsvRefreshIsCached AND NetFxFullRefresh_InstalledReleaseExists AND NetFxFullRefresh_InstalledRelease >= 461833' evaluates to false.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i101: Detected package: netfxfullrefreshisv, state: Absent, cached: None
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i101: Detected package: netfx_472mtpack.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i101: Detected package: netfx_472mtpacklp.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i101: Detected package: netfxsdk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i101: Detected package: netfx472_bootstrapper2015.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:10]i052: Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 1' evaluates to true.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]i052: Condition 'RebootPending = 0 OR IgnorePendingReboot = 1' evaluates to true.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]i052: Condition 'Privileged' evaluates to true.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]i052: Condition '((VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR      (VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT (OSInstallationType = "Client")) OR      (VersionNT = v6.3) OR      (VersionNT = v10.0 AND OSBuildNumber >= 14393) OR      (VersionNT > v10.0))' evaluates to false.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]e000: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack is not supported on this Operating System.
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: ((VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR      (VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT (OSInstallationType = "Client")) OR      (VersionNT = v6.3) OR      (VersionNT = v10.0 AND OSBuildNumber >= 14393) OR      (VersionNT > v10.0))
[1F70:1E7C][2019-01-09T09:48:11]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This issue was apparently because my particular build of Windows 10 was quite old, and genuinely is not supported.**

I was not able to 100% confirm this, because running [the Windows 10 Updater](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027667/windows-10-update) failed multiple times on this PC (and so I gave up trying it) but several key things indicate this is the case:

- Windows 10 build on the PC was **10240**
- But in the log the 472 installer wanted OSBuildNumber ≥ **14393**
- Different releases of Windows 10 have different levels of support by the framework. My particular install might have been an early or pre-release, because its version # (1701) is not listed at all on https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved this issue, by starting from a lower version and then step by step updating to a newer version. You can download the latest and previous versions from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework-runtime/net472).

So In my case, I had to first install `.NET Framework 4.5.2` then the latter ones and so on and so forth.

OS: Windows 8 (***Not 8.1*** | PS: I hate windows updates)

Comment: What was the build of Windows O/S you were using?

Comment: Updated the info.

Comment: Thanks but I meant the actual build number, like "14393" - not the marketing version (8, 10, etc.)

Comment: Umm...sorry I don't have that anymore, as I decided to just upgrade to win 10, due to some other issue :D

Comment: This is not really an answer to this question. It actually reads like the OP posted an answer to his own question (which he also did), but seems to be the solution to something similar on a different version of the operating system, for a different reason. Please let the answer section be for actual answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

open CMD as administrator

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx4 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-NonHTTP-Activation /all
```

Restart if required and you are good to go.

Comment: Working fine for me