# The problem with the download of the Net.Framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What to do? I'm trying to connect Visual Studio Code to Unity. 
4.7.2 does not install due to: "not supported by your operating system"(Windows 10) 
What to do :`)

Sorry for the translation inaccuracies.

Error:

**This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET
Framework:
.NET Framework, Version=v4.7.2
Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?**

[Here is this mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50uVp.png)

Comment: So have you installed .NET 4.7.2?

Comment: Solve the missing SDK problem.

Comment: It is not installed, they say "not supported by your operating system" I have Windows 10 is quite strange ._.

Comment: vscode can only support projects that target .NETCore.  You'll need to use Visual Studio for Unity projects.  https://forum.unity.com/threads/dotnet-core-3-0-released-when-unity.749786/

Comment: If I recall correctly, you are supposed to get .NET 4.7.2 runtime as an update in Windows 10, so you get it from Windows Updates. If that is the case, it makes sense that the runtime installer is not compatible with Windows 10. You still need an SDK. One thing is building for a .NET target (for that you need the SDK) and another is running on that .NET target (for that you need the runtime).

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883840/11780141