# C# project wants .NET 4.7.1 but I can't install it

Tags: c#

I need to work on a very old C# project that uses various versions of the .NET application framework including 3.5, when opening the project this dialog is shown:

[image]

So I downloaded .NET 4.7.1 which can't be installed because a newer version of the .NET framework is already installed.

So why is VS 2019 not offering the .NET 4.8.03762 version that is installed then?
I would assume 4.x being downward compatible... is it not?

My second question is why is vs suggesting to use .NET 4.6.1 anyways, looking at the various keys in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
```

I don't see 4.6.1 at all?

Comment: The VS project settings has a TARGET option to use older Net versions.

Comment: You can install a required targeting pack using VS installer

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883840/11780141

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the Visual Studio Installer (menu **Tools** -> **Get Tools and Features**) and install required .NET Framework targeting packs (and SDKs, if needed)
[image]

Another option is to downgrade the project target framework to the version, installed on your machine (to .NET 4.6.1, as it shown on your screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the target framework version to the latest framework version available on your machine.

[image]

Comment: i changed it to 4.8 but for that i had to also install the part to target 4.8 platforms, however i have to get some nuget packages from a private server tomorrow to test the whole application